# PHP unable to format Datetime to correct string format

Tags: php, datetime

I have this format:

How do I use PHP `DateTime` to format like `2023-01-27T17:37:00.000Z`

So far I have

```
$date = new DateTime();
$string = $date->format('Y-m-dTHH:H:i:s');
```

but it outputs `2022-11-25UTC0000:00:00:00`

What is the correct format

Is there a ressource on the web that would find it for me ? like a helper website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$string = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z');
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime class to format the date like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2023-01-27T17:37:00.000Z');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z'); // Outputs 2023-01-27T17:37:00.000Z
```